# Are pages consuming more server resources than posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, performance

Is there any performance difference between the way wordpress handle pages and posts when i'm querying for them ?

In the same way, is there any performance difference between **hierarchical** custom post types (that are behaving like pages) and **non hierarchical** custom post types (that are behaving like posts) when i'm querying for them ?

The context of this question is : as i'm building a multilingual website and as custom taxonomies slug aren't translatable (in a multilingual context), i was about to simply use native pages (whose slug are translatable) in order to build a parent-page/child-page relationship instead of using custom taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

Pages and posts are identical in performance at first, as they are loaded from the same table: `wp_posts`. However if the theme is including in the render for the page widgets or meta or taxonomies, they could vary greatly on performance, but a priori can't be affirmed one or other is more performant.

It is really a matter of the render and assets that your theme is including. For example a post could be very fast to load and other post in the same could load tons of resources. Same thing for pages. They are basically the same by themselves.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Basically, it means that the hierarchical aspect of the question doesn't have to be taken in consideration as it doesn't consume more resources than the taxonomy way of organizing the website : from the performance point of view, it's more or less the same using parent / child pages than using taxonomies.

Comment: It depends on how many taxonomies or hierarchical features you use. Performance issues comes more often on complex queries or N+1 problem WordPress version